# Transform data in specific format

Tags: r, pivot, gsub

I am working with the data set that contains columns with information about age and sex stored together (e.g Y_0_13_Males, Y_0_13_Females, Y_0_13_Unknown, etc.). Below you can see the dataset

```
structure(list(Y_O_13_Males = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 0), Y_O_13_Females = c(4, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Y_O_13_Unknown = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Y65_And_Over_Males = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Y65_And_Over_Females = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Y65_And_Over_Unknown = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Unknown_And_Over_Males = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Unknown_And_Over_Females = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Unknown_And_Over_Unknown = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I want to convert this data into format that is shown below :

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this and convert data into format showed above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to doing it is to set `names_pattern` in `pivot_longer`, so that each column can be "split" into two parts, with the later part containing the values.

After pivoting the data, we need to set factor for the `Age` column then `arrange` it so that it fits your desired order.

```
library(tidyr)
library(mutate)

df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("Age", ".value"), 
                    names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)") %>% 
  mutate(Age = factor(Age, levels = c("Y_O_13", "Y65_And_Over", "Unknown_And_Over"))) %>% 
  arrange(Age)

# A tibble: 15 × 4
   Age              Males Females Unknown
   <fct>            <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Y_O_13               5       4       1
 2 Y_O_13               0       0       0
 3 Y_O_13               0       0       0
 4 Y_O_13               0       0       0
 5 Y_O_13               0       0       0
 6 Y65_And_Over         0       0       0
 7 Y65_And_Over         0       0       0
 8 Y65_And_Over         0       0       0
 9 Y65_And_Over         0       0       0
10 Y65_And_Over         0       0       0
11 Unknown_And_Over     0       0       0
12 Unknown_And_Over     0       0       0
13 Unknown_And_Over     0       0       0
14 Unknown_And_Over     0       0       0
15 Unknown_And_Over     0       0       0
```